# What is a good data structure to save a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures

I am designing a word filter that can filter out bad words (200 words in list) in an article (about 2000 words). And there I have a problem that what **data structure** I need to save this bad word list, so that the program can **use a little time to find the bad word** in articles?

-- more details

If the size of bad word list is 2000, the article is 50000, and the program will procedure about 1000 articles one time. Which **data structure** I should choose, a less then O(n^2) solution in searching?

Comment: Even a stupid `O(n ^ 2)` search algorithm (I don't think anyone has ever invented such thing but still) would be able to do that in very little time since 200 and 2000 words are a *small* set of data. So, you don't really need to worry about performance until it is provably degraded. However, the usual data structure to store an unordered set of data in is a hash table.

Comment: What is your target language ? A lot of them have built-in set and/or map possibly implemented with hash tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashTable because its average complexity is O(1) for insert and search and your data just 2000 words.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: But pesimistic complexity of hashtable is `O(n)`. Set always gives `O(log_2(n))`

Comment: "The complexity of a single operation is O(n). Which makes sense: if all keys have the same hash, then they all go into the same bucket, which is just an array or a linked list, so it needs to be searched linearly."

Comment: @Ty221 Binary trees have log_2 complexity, sets can be implemented with hash tables too.

Answer (score 1):

A *dictionary* usually is a mapping from one thing (word in 1st language) to another thing (word in 2nd language). You don't seem to need this mapping here, but just a set of words.

Most languages provide a **set** data structure out of the box that has `insert` and membership testing methods.

A small example in Python, comparing a `list` and a `set`:

```
import random
import string
import time

def create_word(min_len, max_len):
    return "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in
                    range(random.randint(min_len, max_len+1))])

def create_article(length):
    return [create_word(3, 10) for _ in range(length)]

wordlist = create_article(50000)
article = " ".join(wordlist)
good_words = []
bad_words_list = [random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(2000)]

print("using list")
print(time.time())
for word in article.split(" "):
    if word in bad_words_list:
        continue
    good_words.append(word)

print(time.time())

good_words = []
bad_words_set = set(bad_words_list)

print("using set")
print(time.time())
for word in article.split(" "):
    if word in bad_words_set:
        continue
    good_words.append(word)

print(time.time())
```

This creates an "article" of 50000 randomly created "words" with a length between 3 and 10 letters, then picks 2000 of those words as "bad words".

First, they are put in a `list` and the "article" is scanned word by word if a word is `in` this list of bad words. In Python, the `in` operator tests for membership. For an unordered list, there's no better way than scanning the whole list.

The second approach uses the `set` datatype that is initialized with the list of bad words. A `set` has no ordering, but *way* faster lookup (again using the `in` keyword) if an element is contained. That seems to be all you need to know.

On my machine, the timings are:

```
using list
1421499228.707602
1421499232.764034
using set
1421499232.7644095
1421499232.785762
```

So it takes about 4 seconds with a list and 2 hundreths of a second with a set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best structure, you can use there is `set`.  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29

I takes `log_2(n)` time to add element to structure (once-time operation) and the same answer every query. So if you will have 200 elements in data structure, your program will need to do only about 8 operations to check, does the word is existing in `set`.

Comment: A hash table has even better asymptotical complexity…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant `set` is easier to implement and more understandable. I do not think, OP wants to read this whole book -http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/

Comment: I don't see how it would be "more understandable" – you don't have to name your hash table `HashTable` – you can call it `WordSet` if you name your data structures semantically (as you should). As to the ease of implementation – that's mostly subjective… a naive hash table with chained collision resolution is just as trivial to implement as a simple binary search tree. (Even better, advanced self-balancing BSTs, like the red-black tree, seem actually harder to implement to me than even an efficient open-addressed hash table.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Pesimistic complexity of hashtable is `O(n)`

Comment: And? so is that of a BST. Also, it's the average case complexity that usually matters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Bag` data structure for this problem. In a `Bag` data structure elements have no order but is designed for fast lookup of an element in the `Bag`. It time complexity is `O(1)`. So for N words in an article overall complexity turns out to be `O(N)`. Which is the best you can achieve in this case. Java `Set` is an example of `Bag` implementation in Java.